# POST JSON to API and retrieve data with PHP

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I'm trying to use [this API](http://e20prodwebapi.esmartapi.com/Help/Api/POST-api-Authenticate) and POST to it with the required parameters.

Using this code:

```
function postToService_php( $urlAbs, $data ) {
    $dataJSON = json_encode($data);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlAbs);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dataJSON);                                                                  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($dataJSON))                                                                       
    );
    $resultJSON = curl_exec($ch);
    return $resultJSON;
}

$postData = array(
    'UserName' => '*username*',
    'Password' => '*password*',
    'Area' => 1
);

var_dump(postToService_php('http://e20prodwebapi.esmartapi.com/api/Authenticate', $postData));
```

This seems to give string(0) "" as a result, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: As a test, try adding `$info=curl_getinfo( $ch );return $info;` to your curl function and see what that reveals. For me ( no username / password ) I was getting a 403 response

Comment: I seem to get the same response, with username and password.
EDIT: According to "Returns 200-OK with information about the user, 401-Unauthorized or 410-Gone if the user doesn't exist in this area (net or power)." it should give 410 if the user doesn't exist, right?

Comment: I couldn't see a way to register so can't test further - though using https did return a 401

Comment: Awesome, https did the trick! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this API https is required. I don't have account so can't test.

```
https://e20prodwebapi.esmartapi.com/api/Authenticate
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this: Consider you have to use SSL for this site (HTTPS)

```
<?php

function postToService_php( $urlAbs, $data ) {
    $dataJSON = json_encode($data);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlAbs);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dataJSON);                                                                  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); //Remove this line if everything works okay.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 20);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($dataJSON))                                                                       
    );
    $resultJSON = curl_exec($ch);

    return $resultJSON;
}

$postData = array(
    'UserName' => 'test',
    'Password' => 'test',
    'Area' => 1
);

var_dump(postToService_php('https://e20prodwebapi.esmartapi.com/api/Authenticate', $postData));
```

Answer (score 1):

On a hunch I tried https and received the expected 401 response using this code

```
function postToService_php( $url, $data ) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $data=json_encode( $data );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );

    if( parse_url( $url,PHP_URL_SCHEME )=='https' ){
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, realpath( 'c:/wwwroot/cacert.pem' ) );
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );                                                                     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data );  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );                                                               
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen( $data ))                                                                       
    );

    $result = curl_exec( $ch );
    $info=curl_getinfo( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    return (object)array(
        'result'=>  $result,
        'info'  =>  $info
    );
}


$url='https://e20prodwebapi.esmartapi.com/api/Authenticate';
$postData = array(
    'UserName' => 'geronimo',
    'Password' => 'passthedoobie',
    'Area' => 1
);

print_r( postToService_php( $url, $postData ) );
```